# Make this more OOPey? - good structure?

Tags: oop, static, structure

I just want advice on whether I could improve structure around a particular class which handles all disk access functions

The structure of  my program is that I have a class called Disk which gets data from flatfiles and databases on a, you guessed it, hard disk drive. I have functions like

LoadTextFileToStringList,
WriteStringToTextFile,
DeleteLineInTextFile
etc

which are kind of "generic methods"

In the same class I also have some more specific methods such as GetXFromDisk where X might be a particular field in a database table/query.

Should I separate out the generic methods from the specialised. Should I make another class which inherits the generic methods. At the moment my class is static as there is no need to have an internal state of the class.

I'm not really OOPing am I?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: If there's no internal state, why is it a class at all? What's wrong with good old module-level functions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using only static static functions you are not really OOPing as you said. It is writing procedural code in OO language.

You should look to create classes which represent objects in your problem domain like `File` and `TextFile`. These classes should have operations like `DeleteLine`, `WriteLIne`, `Load` etc.

Also, in which ever language you are programming, it is likely to have a good File IO library. Try to use that in your code as much as possible. If needed just write wrappers over the library classes to provide some additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you seem to have in your code is a Utilities class where you bundle in all the file methods.
This could indicate some design issue but IMHO it is ok, since it is common to have utility classes in OOP designs.
It haves the benefit of being able to add extra methods or modify existing ones easy since you will not have any derived classes extending the Utility class to be affected.
For example java has static methods everywhere. E.g. `Collection` class.
I would suggest to have the class's contructor be `private` and have the naming such that is obvious that this is a Utilities class.